# C# MySQL Search query

Tags: c#, mysql

This code has a function to search for the patient's room assignment:

```
else if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from patientinfo where LastName and FirstName = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con.con);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Read())
    {
        label2.Text = dr.GetString("LastName") + "," + dr.GetString("FirstName");
        label6.Text = dr.GetString("Room");
        if(label6.Text == "506")
        {
            label3.Text = "Payward Building";          
        }                
        else if(label6.Text == "507")                
        {                
            label3.Text = "Payward Building";                    
        }                    
    }
    else
    {                     
        MessageBox.Show("No Data! Please Try Again", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);                        
        con.Close();                     
    }
```

I am having difficulties to search for the patient name, which is stored as two different fields in the database, `FirstName` and `LastName`. I want only to input on the combination of the first name and last name.

Comment: `where LastName != FirstName`?

Comment: It looks like your code is missing an `if` statement after the `label6.Text = dr.GetString("Room");` line.  Is that a typo?  Also consider properly indenting your code to make it more readable.

Comment: nope, it might look for data first in the last name and secondly search for first name. Thanks for helping me out,

Comment: @EnnT Don't post corrected code in a comment.  Edit your question instead.

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't see the Edit question at all, Thanks for reminding me man.

Comment: @EnnT Do you want to find all the patients who's first or last name contains the text in textBox?

Comment: @FelixAv Yes, but I can't find a right solution on that. If I input the full name which is the combination of the first and last name, there are no results found somehow it causes an error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change you SQL code to that:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from patientinfo where LastName + ' ' + FirstName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con.con);
```

Comment: It seems just replace like into =. Thanks for the great help man.